Доступ к частным переменным
Такой доступ к частным переменным (без их изменения!) - насколько безопасен и приемлим?
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private_var = 66


class_instance = MyClass()
print(class_instance._MyClass__private_var)


Мне кажется проблем с безопасностью не будет, но выглядит это отвратно.

Если нужно читать переменную, не делайте её частной/закрытой/приватной. Зачем?

Безопасно - это не про питон. В нём нет механизмов, позволяющих полностью исключить внешние изменения переменных класса и экземпляра класса. Есть только договорённости.

Private переменные: доступны только внутри класса
с префиксом двойного подчеркивания (__).
Тем не менее, можно получить к нему доступ,
используя версию с искаженным именем,
print(class_instance._MyClass__private_var)

хотя это не рекомендуется.
Делайте так:
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.__private_var = var

    def display_private_var(self):
        print(f"__private_var: {self.__private_var}")  # Доступно внутри класса


class_instance = MyClass(66)
class_instance.display_private_var() 


это называется getter
